# To find trace of sub-matrices in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a bigger matrix of dimension `3Nx3N`. I need to find trace of each `submatrix` of dimension 3x3. I have found answers on SO for splitting the bigger matrix into smaller `submatrices` but I can't find a way to store them and find trace for each submatrices in `Python`. Any suggestion would be of immense help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: how is the 3n x 3n matrix stored (in what order)? Are the 3x3 blocks adjacent? Are you using numpy?

Comment: Hello. Yes the 3x3 blocks are adjacent and I am using numpy.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `numpy` has a `trace()` method on its arrays, so you can just use:

```
list( a[3*m:3*m+3,3*m:3*m+3].trace() for m in range(n) )
```

Here, the slicing `3*m:3*m+3,3*m:3*m+3` pulls out each submatrix, and then applies the trace to it. This is probably not the most efficient way to do what you want, but it is transparent.

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick solution. It is exactly what I want. Thank you again. :)